# Asyncronous tasks in PHP on shared hosting

Tags: php, asynchronous

I want to allow the user to post a form and have it trigger additional processes, such as sending emails and executing functions. However, if I run this inline with the user submitting the form then it will take a long time for the form to submit.

What options do I have to run processes asynchronously if I am in a shared hosting environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question and I'm not getting a lot of help. Shared hosts dont offer celery so I'm a bit stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of solutions to this.

1. The first is to use AJAX and handle each action (running a function, sending an email, etc) as a single http request.
2. The other is to use a cron task to execute these actions from a queue stored on the server. The cron task can be set to run every minute or so, so the queue will be processed pretty quickly, but the user does not have to wait while this is happening. You can implement the queue in a file or in database - whatever works best for you.

You mentioned a confirmation step that follows the form submission - this would not be a problem in either case. Store the data in a session, and then when you have reached the stage where you are ready to run these actions (after confirmation, for instance), you can use or another of the approaches I mentioned above.

For the AJAX solution, you would be able to store the required data from the form on the final html page (in hidden inputs). Each action would be fired by javascript as a single http request (you could group them together, as the execution of this server side script is invisible to the user, so a relatively long execution would not be a problem).

There are 2 problems I can see with the AJAX approach :

1. It depends on Javascript, which may be disabled on the user's browser.
2. The user could navigate away from the page before all of the actions had been completed.

For these reasons, I would prefer the cron solution.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-threading isn't supported in PHP by default.

You could use AJAX to post off multiple requests simultaneously though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't support asynchronous threads as default. You could write the text into a mysql and call a special file with a cronjob which only submits the rows of mysql.

An other way to solve this: You can send the request with AJAX. By this way, the user don't see, how much time is need to get the response.

Comment: Ok so I write to a DB and poll it with a cron job? That's an option, although a "push" system would be better if possible

Comment: @jan - well this could work in some way, but it would be very complicated to setup. plus you'd never get feedback back to your application if a function call succeeded, etc.

Answer (score 1):

use `AJAX` to send your emails and execute other functions, for example by using the `jQuery` library: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

`AJAX` means "Asynchronous Javascript And XML" and would exactly fit your needs.

Comment: The trouble is, the email would only be able to be sent on form submit - I dont want to send them confirmation before they have confirmed, in which case would ajax give me any savings?

Comment: @JamesWillson - with AJAX you could execute different PHP files at the "same" time in an asynchronous way. you can submit your form using AJAX and have another AJAX routine send out the email. so the form submitting process doesn't have to wait for the email to be send and vice versa.